# Wildfly Swarm: problems configuring custom datasource

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly, wildfly-swarm

So, I defined a custom datasource to connect to my MySQL database, but upon launch, Wildfly Swarm gives me the following error:

> 2018-09-27 10:37:23,213 ERROR
>   [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (main) WFLYCTL0013:
>   Operation ("add") failed - address: (("deployment" =>
>   "my-application.war")) - failure description: {
>       "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.CustomDS"],
>       "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
>           "jboss.persistenceunit.\"my-application.war#my-application\" is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.CustomDS]",
>           "jboss.persistenceunit.\"my-application.war#my-application\".**FIRST_PHASE**
>   is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.CustomDS]"
>       ] } 2018-09-27 10:37:23,218 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (main) WFLYSRV0021: Deploy of deployment "my-application.war" was rolled
>   back with the following failure message:  {
>       "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.CustomDS"],
>       "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
>           "jboss.persistenceunit.\"my-application.war#my-application\" is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.CustomDS]",
>           "jboss.persistenceunit.\"my-application.war#my-application\".**FIRST_PHASE**
>   is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.CustomDS]"
>       ] }

My configuration is the following:

**persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
        <persistence-unit name="primary" transaction-type="JTA">

        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/CustomDS</jta-data-source>

        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.default_batch_fetch_size" value="16" />
            <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="100" />
            <property name="hibernate.order_inserts" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.order_updates" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.requireSSL" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.jdbc.time_zone" value="CEST"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**standalone.xml**

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:5.0">
                <xa-datasource jdni-name="java:jboss/datasources/CustomDS" pool-name="CustomDS">
                    <driver>mysql</driver>
                    <xa-datasource-property name="ServerName">localhost</xa-datasource-property>
                    <xa-datasource-property name="DatabaseName">mydb</xa-datasource-property>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>someusername</user-name>
                        <password>somepassword</password>
                    </security>
                    <validation>
                        <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLValidConnectionChecker"></valid-connection-checker>
                        <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLExceptionSorter"></exception-sorter>
                    </validation>
                </xa-datasource>
                <drivers>
                    <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                        <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                    </driver>
                    <driver name="mysql" module="com.mysql">
                        <driver-class>com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
                        <xa-datasource-class>com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                    </driver>
                </drivers>
            </datasources>
        </subsystem>
```

I tried everything, including manually deploying MySQL driver, but nothing seems to be working... Any advice? Do I need to define something creating a web.xml file?

Comment: Have you tried using `project-defaults.yml` to configure the DataSource instead?

Comment: @Ken is there a template to try to use it?

Comment: An example is https://github.com/kenfinnigan/ejm-samples/blob/master/chapter11/kafka-consumer/src/main/resources/project-defaults.yml

Comment: @Ken still no luck. Same error as before.